# Spring Jpa concurrent transaction and stale data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-data

I'm using spring jpa in my project.

I've a service with a synchonized method:

```
@Service("venditaCustom")
@Transactional
public class VenditaCustomRepositoryImpl implements VenditaCustomRepository {

@Override   
public synchronized <S extends Vendita> S salva(S vendita, Long idPrenotazione)      throws Exception {
    if (idPrenotazione == null || idPrenotazione < 0) {
        return salva(vendita);
    } else {
        return salvaDaPrenotazione(vendita, idPrenotazione);
    }
}
```

This method send request to the method salva or salvaDaPrenotazione.

```
public <S extends Vendita> S salva(S vendita) throws Exception {
....do many operation on object Vendita.....
int numeroFiscale = getNumeroBiglietto();   
...
manager.persist(vendita);
manager.flush();
```

the method getNumeroBiglietto() do a query to obtain the last sequence number:

```
private int getNumeroBiglietto() {      
    String sQuery = "SELECT MAX(numero) FROM Biglietto WHERE anno = :anno ";
    Query q = manager.createQuery(sQuery);
    q.setParameter("anno", new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    Integer maxNum = 0;
    try {
        maxNum = (Integer) q.getSingleResult();         
        if (maxNum == null)
            maxNum = 0;
            } catch (NoResultException e) {

        maxNum = 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("", e);
        maxNum = 0;
    }
    if (maxNum == null || maxNum == 0) {
        maxNum = PRIMO_NUMERO_FISCALE_BIGLIETTI;
    } else {
        maxNum++;
    }
    log.trace("maxNum " + maxNum);
    return maxNum;
}
```

The method salvaDaPrenotazione is quite similar to salva():

```
    public <S extends Vendita> S salvaDaPrenotazione(S vendita, Long idPrenotazione)     throws Exception {
 ...do many action on object Vendita
int numeroFiscale = getNumeroBiglietto();
.....
manager.persist(vendita);
manager.flush();
```

***The problem:*** I do this action in sequence:

- call indirectly method salvaDaPrenotazion() with big data so the method take long time to complete (about 7s)
- before first method finish I call indirectly method salva()

You can see that:
- when you enter in method salvaDaPrenotazione() you get the correct MAX(numero) (is the last value of sequence saved on db)
- at the end of the method salvaDaPrenotazion() after persist and flush doing a call to getNumeroBiglietto() I've the correct updated value from db
- when you enter in the method salva() and i get the value MAX(numero) from db I've a wrong value! I've a stale value, the same I got at the start of method salvaDaPrenotazione() as if this transaction don't see the commit of the other transaction.
So the transaction fails with a

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

Note that:

- there is a unique enter point that is

  public synchronized  S salva(S vendita, Long idPrenotazione) throws   Exception {

and this method is syncronized.

- the transaction isolation is DEFAULT in spring jpa and READ_COMMITTED in my.cnf (I'm using Mysql)
- If you retry to call indirectly the method salva() after first fail it works!

I don't understand where can be the problem. I don't think is related to cache problem, maybe to isolation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use this for sequencing?  It won't work as every process calling that query will all get the same value, unless you guarantee they are only executed sequentially via  locking.  Pessimistic locking would need to be done on the query so that no other process can issue the same query until the first process is done its update.
Rather than reinventing the wheel though, you should just use a database or JPA sequencing strategy, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

Comment: You're right Chris, I'm using a sequence but quite particular. Think my sequence as fiscal numbers for invoices. So numbers must be sequential, must not be holes between them,an object added first must have a sequence number less than an object added after.Furthermore every year the sequence must start from 1.For this I created a syncronized method. Anyway I can't understand why at the end of first request, when start the second request/transaction, query MAX(numero) returns old value!

Comment: Timing.  Each transaction is isolated, you cannot see changes made in one outside the transaction until it fully commits.  Check that the commit has occurred before your second query is issued.  You need a way to force it to occur after the commit, such as locking at the database level

Comment: Hi Chris,I think that with @Transactional of Spring Data the commit is made outer of my method in a its interceptor. So I think the best way is to manage manually the opening and closing of the transaction.

Comment: It will help in this case.  You may want to put in code to retry your sequencing logic and insert should a duplicate occurs, and make the transaction containing the insert as quick as possible to reduce the chance of collisions incase you ever wish to reuse this code in another process.